# analyze periodic signal using simulink in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink

let us suppose that we have following model of time series

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17784/minimum-frequency-in-periodic-components

i want to  simulate this model using simulink, but dont know exactly how to do?i can simple generate  simple model using sine function,but what about sum ?what type of sources or sink i should use? i need  two output -first output should be time domain based second one should be its  power spectrum using periodogram  is it possible to do so?please could you help me or give me some hint in this task?let us immagine that sampling frequency is 100 and  total observation time is 2.94 second. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are plenty of blocks in Simulink to do what you need:

- [Sine Wave](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/sinewave.html) source block
- [Sum](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/sum.html) block
- various sink blocks (in the time domain). It's up to you to decide what block is best suited to your application.

Simulink is time-based, you can save the (time-domain) output to the MATLAB workspace and perform an FFT on it to get frequency-domain information. If you have the [DSP System Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/dsp-system/), there are additional blocks for signal processing. The [Signal Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/signal/) (which is a pre-requisite for the DSP System Toolbox) provides a [`periodogram`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/periodogram.html) function.

Comment: PS: a good place to start would be some basics tutorials with Simulink, e.g. https://www.mathworks.co.uk/academia/student_center/tutorials/slregister.html and https://www.mathworks.co.uk/academia/student_center/tutorials/signal-processing-tutorial.html

Comment: could you help me please with graphical picture?

Comment: I don't have access to Simulink anymore. It's really not that hard, you need to have a go at it yourself. You'll find that people are much more willing to help you if you show some effort on your part.

Comment: i mean  i can  use blocks like sine   and so on,but how to construct this is question

Comment: Like I said, you need to start with some basic tutorials and then have a go. Drag and drop the blocks, connect them, parameterise them correctly, set your simulations settings appropriately and that's all there is to it.

Comment: if i need   3 sinusoidal block ok,but what about 100? :D

Comment: i  understood  now about signal part,what about white noise part?

Comment: If you look in the sources blocks, you'll find a band-limited white noise block.

Comment: what if it is not band-limited?

Comment: Have you actually had a look at the documentation of the block? Use a random number block if you want.

Comment: Again, look at the documentation of the blocks, it explains about specifying the sample time. You really need to get familiar with Simulink first (tutorials).